# Set selection in unit test for custom select not working in Angular 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have implemented a custom select control that uses a native html select internally.
The selected option is bound via `[(ngModel)]` to the custom select.

In my unit test I initialize a variable with a valid id to preselect in the select element, but it does not work.

Here is the code:

my-select.component.html:

```
<select
  #select
  (change)="onChange($event)"
  (blur)="onBlur()">

  <option *ngFor="let optionItem of options"
          [value]="optionItem.id !== undefined ? optionItem.id : optionItem.key"
          [selected]="'' + optionItem.id === selectedOption || optionItem.key === selectedOption">
    {{ optionItem.value }}
  </option>

</select>
```

my-select.component.ts

```
import {
  Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, forwardRef, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-select',
  templateUrl: './my-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-select.component.css'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MySelectComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class MySelectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  /**
  * Internal select element.
  */
  @ViewChild('select') selectElement: ElementRef;

  @Input() options: any[];

  @Output() select = new EventEmitter<string | number>();

  /**
  * Currently selected option.
  */
  selectedOption?: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  /**
  * Handling user's select change.
  * @param {Event} event
  */
  onChange(event: Event) {
    const element = <HTMLSelectElement>this.selectElement.nativeElement;
    this.selectedOption = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

    this.propagateAndEmitValue();
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.onTouched();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.options && changes.options.currentValue && changes.options.currentValue.length > 0) {
      if (!this.isSelectedOptionAvailableInOptions()) {
        this.selectFirstOption();
      }
    }
  }

  /**
  * Write a new value to the element.
  */
  writeValue(obj: any) {
    if (obj !== undefined && obj !== null) {
      this.selectedOption = '' + obj;
    } else {
      this.selectFirstOption();
      this.propagateAndEmitValue();
    }
  }

  /**
  * Set the function to be called when the control receives a change event.
  */
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
  /**
  * Set the function to be called when the control receives a touch event.
  */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  /**
  * the method set in registerOnChange, it is just
  * a placeholder for a method that takes one parameter,
  * we use it to emit changes back to the form
  * @param _
  */
  private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };

  /**
  * Property saves angular callback method that has to be called on touch event.
  */
  private onTouched = () => {};

  /**
  * Propagates new value to angular and emits select event.
  */
  private propagateAndEmitValue() {
    if (this.options) {
      const selectValue = parseInt(this.selectedOption || '0', 10);
      this.propagateChange(selectValue);
      this.select.emit(selectValue);
    }
  }

  /**
  * Check if selectedOption is a valid option, i.e. it is available in the options list.
  * @returns {boolean} true, if selectedOption is available, otherwise false
  */
  private isSelectedOptionAvailableInOptions() {
    return this.options.some(option => '' + option.id === this.selectedOption);
  }

  /**
  * Selects first select option.
  */
  private selectFirstOption() {
    this.selectedOption = '' + this.options[0].id;
  }
}
```

my-select.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {MySelectComponent} from './my-select.component';

@Component({
  template: `<app-my-select
    [options]="options"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
    (select)="select($event)"></app-my-select>`
})
class TestComponent {
  options: any[];
  selectedOption: string;

  select() {}
}

describe('MySelectComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  const idSelectOptionsStub = [
    { id: 0, value: '' },
    { id: 1, value: 'First Text' },
    { id: 2, value: 'Second Text' },
    { id: 3, value: 'Third Text' }
  ];

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ TestComponent, MySelectComponent ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.options = idSelectOptionsStub;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should init with given id', () => {
    component.selectedOption = '2';

    const select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select'));
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(select.nativeElement.selectedIndex).toEqual(2);
      expect(select.nativeElement.value).toEqual('2');
      expect(component.selectedOption).toEqual('2');
    });
  });
});
```

When running the only unit test ''should init with given id' I get the following output:

```
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Mac OS X 10.13.2) MySelectComponent should init with given id FAILED
  Expected 0 to equal 2.
      at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/src/app/my-select/my-select.component.spec.ts:53:50
      at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
      at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
  Expected '0' to equal '2'.
      at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/src/app/my-select/my-select.component.spec.ts:54:42
      at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
      at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
  Expected 0 to equal '2'.
      at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/src/app/my-select/my-select.component.spec.ts:55:40
      at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
      at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/pascalchorus/Development/select-test/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
```

My expectation is that the native select should have initially selected the item with id 2, but that is not the case.

Could you please explain what's wrong here?

You can find the example project on GitHub:
https://github.com/pchorus/select-test

Comment: how are you triggering the click event?

Comment: I don't trigger an event at all. I change the selectedOption property of my test component and I expect that the writeValue function is called and that it sets the inner select's value.

Comment: Hey Pascal, Could you find a solution for your problem?